# How do I deal with unknown addresses in my postfix log?

Tags: email, spam, postfix-mta, emailrelay

It seems that mail from unknown recipients/senders are being sent through my postfix server.  I see *a lot* of entries like this, with different shady addresses:

```
Nov 24 15:32:35 XXXXX postfix/smtpd[12363]: 34108BA48C6: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 24 15:32:35 XXXXX postsrsd[13736]: srs_forward: <Brandy46@fortalezatours.com> rewritten as <SRS0+FZUn=XJ=fortalezatours.com=Brandy46@YYYYY.ZZ>
Nov 24 15:32:35 XXXXX postfix/cleanup[13735]: 34108BA48C6: message-id=<01FBBAEAA1755AA9757039879337BBA1@fortalezatours.com>
Nov 24 15:32:35 XXXXX postfix/qmgr[12188]: 34108BA48C6: from=<SRS0+FZUn=XJ=fortalezatours.com=Brandy46@YYYYY.ZZ>, size=1196, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 24 15:32:35 XXXXX amavis[13918]: (13918-01) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, [222.92.30.22]:49947 [222.92.30.22] <Brandy46@fortalezatours.com> -> <lizun25@ukr.net>, Queue-ID: 8F805BA48C7, Message-ID: <01FBBAEAA1755AA9757039879337BBA1@fortalezatours.com>, mail_id: qF8LOG1vGb3f, Hits: 2.58, size: 768, queued_as: 34108BA48C6, 2235 ms
Nov 24 15:32:35 XXXXX postfix/smtp[13887]: 8F805BA48C7: to=<lizun25@ukr.net>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=5.3, delays=2.4/0/0.84/2.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 34108BA48C6)
Nov 24 15:32:35 XXXXX postfix/smtp[13676]: 34108BA48C6: to=<lizun25@ukr.net>, relay=mxs.ukr.net[212.42.77.251]:25, delay=0.25, delays=0.17/0/0.04/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1c9v4l-000JFT-EP)
Nov 24 15:32:35 XXXXX postfix/qmgr[12188]: 34108BA48C6: removed
```

(My server name and domain is replaced with XXXXX and YYYYY.ZZ)

Here's my main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU) 
biff = no 
append_dot_mydomain = no 
readme_directory = no 
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/mail.XXXXX.no.crt 
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/mail.XXXXX.no.key 
smtpd_use_tls = yes 
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache 
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache 
myhostname = ZZZZZ.XXXXX.no 
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases 
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases 
myorigin = /etc/mailname 
mydestination = XXXXX.no, ZZZZZ.XXXXX.no, mail.XXXXX.no, localhost.XXXXX.no, localhost 
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION" 
mailbox_size_limit = 0 
recipient_delimiter = + 
inet_interfaces = all 
virtual_alias_domains = 
        WWWWW.no, 
        VVVVV.no 
virtual_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual 
virtual_transport = dovecot 
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1 
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot 
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth 
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes 
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination 
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes 
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024 
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings 
smtpd_client_restrictions = 
    permit_mynetworks, 
    permit_sasl_authenticated, 
    reject_unauth_pipelining, 
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, 
message_size_limit = 50000000 
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic 
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination 
sender_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:10001 
recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:10002 
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender 
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient
```

I have a proper SPF record (`"v=spf1 a mx ?all"`).  What more do I need to do?

*EDIT*: It seems this might be happening because I have enabled SRS: https://serverfault.com/questions/746237/is-srs-rewriting-absolutely-necessary-for-a-forwarding-mailserver

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're simply receiving a lot of spam which is then forwarded to other addresses (otherwise you woul'nt be using postsrsd).

So, it could be normal.

Comment: Hmm, OK. But neither the `from` nor the `to` addresses exist on my system.  How can this happen?